# How can I load a file of Python in Julia?

Tags: numpy, jupyter-notebook, julia

Hi I just wanted to use my Module again which I defined in Python.

Here is the Code what I saved in Python.

```
import numpy as np

matrixSize = 10  Qa= np.random.rand(matrixSize, matrixSize) Q_1 = np.dot(Qa, Qa.transpose()) print(Q_1) np.linalg.cholesky(Q_1) ##check if a matrix is positive definite p_1= np.random.uniform(0, 9, size=10) G_1 = np.diag(-1*np.random.uniform(0, 9, size=10)) h_1 = np.random.uniform(-9, 9, size=10)

np.savez_compressed(r'C:\Users\skqkr\Desktop\Semesterarbeit/Chiwan_Q1', Q=Q_1, p=p_1, G=G_1, h=h_1)
```

and I want use this Code in Jupyter with Juliaprogramm so I typed like this.

```
using PyCall
@pyimport numpy
using OSQP
using Compat.SparseArrays
using NPZ

# Define problem data
Matrix10 = npzread("C:/Users/skqkr/Desktop/Semesterarbeit/Chiwan_Q1.npz")
P = sparse(Matrix10['Q'])
q = Matrix10['p']
A = sparse(Matrix10['G']))

u = [Matrix10['h'] ]

# Crate OSQP object
prob = OSQP.Model()

# Setup workspace and change alpha parameter
OSQP.setup!(prob; P=P, q=q, A=A, l=l, u=u, alpha=1)

# Solve problem
results = OSQP.solve!(prob)
```

But there is an Error
`KeyError: key 'Q' not found`

So how can I fix it? because it works very well when I use this Module in Pythonprogramm

Thanks!

Comment: Does `sparse(Matrix10["Q"])` work?

Comment: it works when I use this code in Python but in Julia it doesn't work. I just woder how I can load it. I guess there would be another form to read it...

Comment: In Julia `'` and `"` have different meaning, unlike Python. In your julia code you are using `['Q']` which is wrong (`'Q'` is a `Char`, not a `String`). You should change it to `["Q"]` before searching for other sources of error.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! you are the man have a nice day!!

Comment: Please edit the post title to reflect the actual question asked..